# Question about the wording of a topology problem.

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I was asked to show that the topology $\mathcal{T}_{X\times Y}$ is the smallest topology for which the functions
$$f_X:X\times Y \rightarrow Y , f_X((x,y))=x
$$ 
and $f_y$ are continuous (where $f_Y$ is defined similarly).

It was worded just like this, and I am very confused about what I am being asked to show. Can someone please explain what is meant?

Comment: What part specifically do you not understand? (As a general rule, "I am confused" is not a good thing to say in a question. Much more useful to you is to say "I am confused about the meaning of …"(

Comment: if $f_X:X\times Y \rightarrow Y $, how can $ f_X((x,y))=x$? x belongs to X.

Comment: I guess "smallest" topology means that the only open sets in the topology are those which are forced to exist by the requirement that $f_X$ and $f_Y$ be continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say what was confusing, but I guess it is the word "smallest".  In this context,

> $T$ is the smallest topology  with property $P$

means that you should show:

1. $T$ has property $P$
2. If $S$ has property $P$, then $T$ is a subset of $S$

For topologies, point 2 means that whenever $G$ is an open set in topology $T$, it is also an open set in topology $S$.

Does this help?  If not please comment.

Comment: I think so. So its easy enough to show they are both continuous with the product topology. So then I would assume that $T$ is a topology where these functions are continuous, an then show that every element in $T_{X\times Y}$ is in $T$?

Comment: Yes, I think that is what is wanted.

Comment: OK So is it the case that if $A$ is open in $X$ then $A\times Y$ is open in any topology on $X\times Y$?

Comment: No, that is not true; $X\times Y $ could have the indiscrete topology for example.